# keycloak 21 remote access

Tags: http, keycloak, remote-access

I'm new with keycloak and have some troubles to connect to springboot backend remotely.I've setup a development environment (spring boot, angular, Unity). In this one, I use keycloak as IAM (v21, Quarkus dist) with no proxy. As I am in dev mode, I start keycloak with start-dev arg. What I want to do is to be able to establish communication between an ipad and my backend server deployed on a PC with tomcat 10.

I have an ios App on my ipad. I tried to connect to my backend server with keycloak launched in dev mode. But I can't connect. I read on internet that keycloak does not accept remote connection when launched in dev mode. I tried to configure it for production mode (build keycloak, create certificate, give the pc IP addr as hotname) but with no success.

Is it possible to run keycloak in dev mode and be able to acces my PC with my ipad and how to do it ?
if remote access is not possible, what is the minimum conf to run keycloak in production mode?

I've read keycloak documentation but it is not very clear for me.

Thanks in advance for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Here is my conf to run Keycloak in prod "mode" on my laptop:

```
db=postgres
db-username=keycloak
db-password=change-me
db-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/keycloak

hostname=bravo-ch4mp

http-enabled=true
http-port=8442
https-key-store-file=C:/Users/ch4mp/.ssh/bravo-ch4mp_self_signed.jks
https-key-store-password=change-me
https-port=8443
```

Off course, I have installed Postgresql and defined `keycloak` user (with login enabled) and database (`keycloak` database being owned by `keycloak` user).

The self signed certificates were generated (and also added to `cacerts` and system trusted root certificates) using https://github.com/ch4mpy/self-signed-certificate-generation.

This repo also contains instructions to setup a DNS on your local network to resolve the keycloak instance host by its name (`bravo-ch4mp` in my case, as can be seen in the Keycloak conf above). This means that:

- issuer claim value is https://bravo-ch4mp:8443/realms/master
- this a URI that all devices can use (provided that this devices are configured to use the local DNS off course)

Comment: thanks for your reply ch4mp. I rolled back to a legacy version for now. But i will test your config which is almost similar to mine (i do not use trust store)